# How does python maintain unique identities for instances of builtin immutable types?

Tags: python, immutability, identity

Immutable does not imply unique identity, like the standard numeric types `Fraction` and `Decimal`.

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> Fraction(1, 3) is Fraction(1, 3)
>>> False
```

However, for all builtin immutable types like `tuple`, `str` and `int`, their instances have unique identities.

```
>>> 1 is 1
>>> True
>>> (2-1, 0) is (int('1'), 0)
>>> True
```

To enforce this it seems to me that python uses some dictionaries to keep track of all the creation of these objects so that we cannot create two objects with the same value. It this hypothesis true? Can somebody kindly explains the mechanisms behind the scene?

Comment: For strings, you could have a look at [The internals of Python string interning](http://guilload.com/python-string-interning/)

Comment: Thanks! But that was python2.7. My question was wrong in that immutable stuffs aren't all singleton. Only those cached like small int's or interned strings are. And the `is` operator cannot be used to compare immutable stuffs for their equality reliably.